# How to filter by aggregation bucket?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need a query that returns only result that has 1 bucket.

The query below returns me the access data of a visitor grouped by day.

```
{
    "size" :  0,
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "range" : {
                                "start_time" : {
                                    "gte" : "2019-02-06 00:00:00",
                                    "lte" : "2019-02-11 23:59:59"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "UNIQUE" : {
            "terms" : {
                "size" : 0,
                "field" : "username"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "visits" : {
                    "date_histogram" : {
                        "field" : "start_time",
                        "interval" : "day",
                        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know which ones returned only once in the period. So when you have only 1 bucket, it's ONE. And if it has visited for more than a day (buckets> 1) then it is RECURRENT.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you'd want a list of `users` who have had a unique date or like visited only once in a particular time frame and you'd want both the details, `date` and the `username` to be in the `aggregation`.

I've created a sample mapping, sample documents, aggregation query and how it would appear in the response

### Mapping:

```
PUT mytest
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs": {
      "properties": {
        "username": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "start_time": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

You can see that I've created 6 documents where `John` has visited twice on same date, Jack visits site on two different dates, while `Jane` and `Rob` visited only once in the time-frame for which I will write an aggregation.

```
POST mytest/mydocs/1
{
  "username": "john",
  "start_time": "2018-08-01"
}

POST mytest/mydocs/2
{
  "username": "john",
  "start_time": "2018-08-01"
}

POST mytest/mydocs/3
{
  "username": "jane",
  "start_time": "2018-08-01"
}

POST mytest/mydocs/4
{
  "username": "rob",
  "start_time": "2018-08-01"
}

POST mytest/mydocs/5
{
  "username": "jack",
  "start_time": "2018-08-01"
}

POST mytest/mydocs/6
{
  "username": "jack",
  "start_time": "2018-08-02"
}
```

### Updated Aggregation Request

**Note** I've added two more documents with username `Jack` who visits the site on *two different dates*, username `John` visits the  site *twice on the same date*.

```
POST mytest/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "start_time": {
        "gte": "2017-08-01",
        "lte": "2019-08-01"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "myterms": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 100,
        "field": "username"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "visit_date": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "start_time",
            "interval" : "day",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
          }
        },
        "count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "start_time"
          }
        },
        "equal_one":{  
          "bucket_selector":{  
            "buckets_path":{  
             "count":"count.value"
            },
            "script":"params.count == 1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Response

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 6,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "myterms": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "john",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "count": {
            "value": 1
          },
          "visit_date": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key_as_string": "2018-08-01",
                "key": 1533081600000,
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "jane",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "count": {
            "value": 1
          },
          "visit_date": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key_as_string": "2018-08-01",
                "key": 1533081600000,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "rob",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "count": {
            "value": 1
          },
          "visit_date": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key_as_string": "2018-08-01",
                "key": 1533081600000,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that John now appears in the result as expected even if he has visited site multiple times on same date.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: So close :( We figured John had accessed more than 1x the same day ... he's still UNIQUE. I consider RECORRENT what I accessed more than 1x on different days. With that query you sent me, you're ignoring John as a single visitor.

Comment: So if John has accessed site multiple times on multiple days, only then he is classified as frequent or recurrent. Is that what is expected? Please clarify

Comment: Exactly. I need the query to return the UNIQUE visitors, those who accessed only 1 day (based on range), even though on that day it has accessed more than once.

Already a RECURRING visitor is the one who visited in one day and came back in another day.

In the aggregation result is already returning aggregate per day. However _count returns the amount of documents within that return.

Comment: @fuzeto Please check the answer once again. I've updated it with what you are looking for. Hope it help! :)

Comment: Again, very close. Sorry I did not inform you before, I should have sent you a mapping :( So, my start_time is in the format `yyyy-MM-dd H:i:s` and the cardinality is getting in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Wait I'll test and let you know!! Adding format may change the response. I'll get back to you soon

Comment: Thanks @Kamal, I'm trying here too!

Comment: Finally worked! On **cardinality** I did with **script**, manipulating the date with groovy, like this: `"script": "new Date(doc['start_time'].value).format('yyyy-MM-dd')"`. The question now is performance. But the main one worked !!! I appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Feel free to post your answer and accept it. Would be useful for others who'd be visiting this post.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found was:

```
{
    "size" :  0,
    "query" : {
        {
            "range" : {
                "start_time" : {
                    "gte" : "2019-02-11 00:00:00",
                    "lte" : "2019-02-11 23:59:59"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "UNIQUE" : {
            "terms" : {
                "size" : 0,
                "field" : "username"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "visit_date": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field" : "start_time",
                        "interval" : "day",
                        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    }
                },
                "count": {
                    "cardinality": {
                        "script": "new Date(doc['start_time'].value).format('yyyy-MM-dd')"
                    }
                },
                "equal_one":{  
                    "bucket_selector":{  
                        "buckets_path":{  
                            "count":"count.value"
                        },
                        "script":"count == 1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But performance remains a problem. In an environment with about 1 million records this query does not work very well.

Maybe some query using **Scripted Metrics** would solve, but demand more analysis (doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html)